# Using Double Right Click in C#

Tags: c#, click, mouse

I am fairly new with C# and I want to know if there is a way to implement a double right click in this event handler? Can anyone tell me how? thanks

```
private void pictureBox_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e){
    if(e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
       MessageBox.Show("A");
    }
    else if(e.Button = MouseButtons.Right)
    {
       MessageBox.Show("B");
    }
    else if(e.Button = MouseDoubleClick.Right) <--how to fix this?
    {
       MessageBox.Show("C");
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("D");
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be separating the events?

Comment: @KyloRen yes, but just want to know if there's a way like this?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [ClickCount](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.mousebuttoneventargs.clickcount) propery of  [MouseRightButtonDown](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.mouserightbuttondown) event.

```
private void OnMouseDownClickCount(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ClickCount == 1)
    {
        // one click.
    }
    if (e.ClickCount == 2)
    {
        // two clicks.
    }
}
```

Comment: How can I implement this to my code? or does it have to be in a seperate event?

Comment: @programnub you can use `MouseRightButtonDown`event

Answer (score 0):

Override the WndProc function and listen for WM_RBUTTONDBLCLK, which as can be seen on this [pinvoke](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Enums/WindowsMessages.html) page is {0x0206}.

Then

```
public class RButton : Button
{
    public delegate void MouseDoubleRightClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e);
    public event MouseDoubleRightClick DoubleRightClick;
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        const Int32 WM_RBUTTONDBLCLK = 0x0206;
        if (m.Msg == WM_RBUTTONDBLCLK)
            DoubleRightClick(this, null);
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
}
```